# GCE - basic API usage - Instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I Want to use "Instances" in the Python API...for some reaseon, my code returns an Empty Error:

```
Error: []
```

my code:

```
email = "somecode@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
with open("somefile.p12") as f:
   pkey = f.read()
cred = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(email,key, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write")
compute = build('compute','v1',credentials=cred)
```

then with the simplest API call:

```
compute.instances().list(project="firebase-client", zone="us-central1-f").execute()
```

the error pops...

Comment: You use `pkey = ...` but then use it as `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(email, key, ...)` — is the spelling the issue here?

Comment: Also, here's how I implemented GCE authentication in Python: https://github.com/mbrukman/cloud-launcher/blob/master/src/cloud_launcher.py — note that I'm requesting the compute scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute` there.

Comment: yes, the scope url was indeed the problem. (pkey was ok on my code:) ) thanks :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned and confirmed in the comment, the solution here is to use the right scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute` is what you want for read-write access to Google Compute Engine APIs.

The scope URL in the question code sample: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write` provides read-write access to Google Cloud Storage API instead.